# Integrate Mac OSX Lion Server with SBS 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, mac-osx, windows-sbs-2008, lion

Hoping to gain some valuable knowledge.

I have an SBS2008 Standard server running Exchange 2007 and all the bells and whistles it comes with. Lately we have been adding a few iOS devices such as iPads and iPhones.

Although I have some control over these devices through EMC (remote wipe and such) I don't have as much control as I would like. I also run Blackberry Server which looks after all of the BBs on the network which gives awesome control over these devices.

What I am trying to do is to run Mac OSX Lion server as a virtual machine (licensing aside). I have the machine working and server running.

The purpose of this is to use Apple Profile Manager to oversee the iOS devices.

My question is, how would I somehow get Mac Mail Server to link up with the host Exchange Server to pass emails/OAB to the iOS devices?

OR would I be able to keep the iOS devices attached to the EX2007 system, but somehow still use the Apple Profile Manager to push profile settings to the devices?

I have a specific purpose for this setup. In the event of a staff member deciding it would be better to start moving company data to other non company owned equipment (which has happened before) I need to be able to lock down the device. This can be done in theory with an iOS device through "Find my iPhone", but the problem is all that this app will do is lock the device down with the current user pin number which the staff member already knows.

I am new to OSX but learning everything I can.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think you need Mac OS X Server for your environment when Apple provide all the necessary deployment tools for Windows? http://www.apple.com/support/iphone/enterprise/

Answer (score 0):

OSX fully supports exchange using LDAP in iMail, iCalaner etc. But you can also use Entourage from Ms Office for mac www.Microsoft.com/mac and use it like outlook.

Your Apple Macs can also be configured to authenticate/login against Active Directory by using a command line. iPhone etc also supports exchange using ActiveSync.